# html/css edits not updating in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance if this question seems inane. However it is important to me and I had difficulty finding an existing question, mainly due to syntactic difficulties.

I am developing a website and have MAMP/MySQL set to work in localhost:8888.  This has been working fine for many months now, but recently I noticed that after I had edited my page and reloaded it is in FF, the page was not completely updated. For instance, the CSS for the page was updated but one of the links that linked to my "about page" linked to the older version of my "about page".  And then I would try Chrome and Safari and the page might be OK and sometimes not.  Or if I wait or try several times to load the page it will load correctly.

This is very frustrating when considering efficiency and consistency in design. What could have happened or is my htdocs folder becoming too full? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Try clearing the cache for the specific files you're using.

Comment: Try [bypassing your cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) when you refresh the page.

Comment: thanks guys, much appreciation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's a cache problem. In most Browsers you can deactivate it. For example in Safari you have to activate the developer menu in preferences > advanced. In the developer menu click on disable caches.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution : press `ctrl + shift + delete` Its a browser shortcut for deleting history. Delete the full cache, cookies, etc. and try reloading the page.